# Get name hints for pydantic-based class attributes

Tags: python, pycharm, pydantic

I have the following model

```
class MyClass(BaseModel):
    attr1: str
    attr2: int
```

Then I want to create an instance of MyClass in the next way:

```
obj: MyClass = MyClass(attr1="123", attr2=123)
```

It works as expected and I get a validation error if I try to do something like (wrong type for attr2)

```
obj: MyClass = MyClass(attr1="123", attr2="abc")
```

However, there is an inconvenient thing - no names hints for attr1 and attr2 when I pass it into constructor (attr1=..., attr2=...) so I have to remember names of all model's attributes. Probably, I misunderstood something because I'm new in Python.

Is there any way to get such hints?

P.S. I use pycharm as an ide

Comment: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/pycharm_plugin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Daniil's comment above docs.pydantic.dev/latest/pycharm_plugin <-- this pydantic plugin works! It does exactly what I need

This extension gives you an autocomplete feature for Pydantic-based model fields

So, if you have a model like

```
class MyClass(BaseModel):
    attr1: str
    attr2: int
```

Then you can start write the following code:

obj: MyClass = MyClass(att ... <-- and then you'll get a list of attributes attr1 and attr2 as a hint. It's extremely useful because of 2 reasons at least:

1. You don't need to remember all attributes
2. You save a lot of time avoiding mistakes like using attt1 instead of attr1 and etc.

Comment: Although this may be the correct answer, it does not accurately reflect what someone else may need to do to resolve their issue when they find this down the line. Please give a bit more info so they too can get things solved :) Answer the question: How did this library help? or What is happening differently now?

Comment: nice notice, I've edited my post :)

Comment: Right on! +1'ed